# Why doesn't Visual Studio 2019 show the emulator once it is started in 'Visual Studio Emulator for Android'?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-emulator

I have recently uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 Community edition and installed Visual Studio 2019 Community edition on my PC at home.

I have never managed to get hardware acceleration working because of the problems described here: https://superuser.com/questions/1482586/cannot-launch-an-x86-android-emulator-using-hyperv-but-can-with-haxm-why

However, using Visual Studio 2017 I could use 'Visual Studio Emulator for Android' in the Start menu as shown below:

[image]

I would launch one of the emulators and it would appear in Visual Studio 2017 for debugging as shown below:

[image]

However, Visual Studio 2019 does not show the emulator in Visual Studio once it is started in 'Visual Studio Emulator for Android'.  Is there something I need to configure to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer to your question in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/400998/visual-studio-emulator-for-vs-19.html)

Please, Take a look at the comment of [@Pierce Boggan](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/435068/view.html)

> **Quote**
>
> The Visual Studio Emulator for
>   Android has been deprecated in Visual Studio 2019. More information is
>   available here:
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-upgrade-visual-studio-projects-2019?view=vs-2017
>
> For developers who want to develop Android applications, but have a
>   requirement on Hyper-V, 
>   we worked with Google to introduce support for
>   Hyper-V acceleration to the official Android emulators. This means you
>   can use Google’s Android emulator side-by-side with other Hyper-V
>   based technologies, including Hyper-V VMs, Docker tooling, the
>   HoloLens emulator, and more. This also means that any Android
>   developer on Windows, who also uses Hyper-V, can use a fast Android
>   emulator that will always support the latest Android APIs, works with
>   Google Play Services out of the box, and works with all features in
>   the Android emulator, including camera, geolocation, and Quick Boot.
>
> More information on configuration is available here:
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows#accelerating-with-hyper-v